# Create a Dynamic Query in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I have been using the standard JPA implementation for a while and had no problems creating dynamic queries resulting from algorithms to search for users in a database. However, we are moving to the Spring Framework (an older version - 3.2, unfortunately) and I simply cannot figure out how to create a dynamic query in Spring.

With `javax.persistance.EntityManager`, I could call `createQuery` and give it a string to work with. However, I have found that in Spring I can only use something like the following code where I define the query in an annotation.

```
@Repository
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Override
    List<Person> findAll(Sort sort);

    @Override
    List<Person> findAll();

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p ORDER BY p.lname ASC, p.fname ASC, p.mname ASC")
    List<Person> findAllSort();

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE UPPER(p.userName) = UPPER(?1)")
    Person findPersonByUsername(String username);


}
```

---

Here is the simplest dynamic query example I could give you that I would like to replicate for Spring:

```
public List<Person> getPersons(List<Long> perIds) {
    List<Person> persons;
    String whereClause = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < perIds.size(); i++) {
        if (i != 0)
            whereClause += " OR ";
        whereClause += "p.perId = '" + perIds.get(i) + "'";
    }
    persons = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE " + whereClause).getResultList();
    return persons;
}
```

---

**Maybe a better question** here is to ask if it is possible or if I should just keep my implementation using the Entity Manager. That being said, would anyone *recomend* me to change my code from using the EntityManager over to using the Spring Framework?

Comment: Can you clear this up a bit? Maybe provide an example of what you *want* to do? When you say "change from entity manager to spring framework" ...  that doesn't make any sense to me, they aren't mutually exclusive concepts, or even necessarily related.

Comment: What I was really hoping to find was that Spring might have its own implementation of the 'createQuery' method so that I can perform either a JPA or naive query. However, if Spring does not offer is own implementation of the createQuery function, I can just keep my current implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring *allows* you to use `@Repository`, but does not *force* you to do so. Spring even offers a nice interfacing of JPA that separates the low level concerns (Datasource definition, and transaction management) from the high level ones (DAO, with declarative transactions).

There is a [chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.13.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-jpa) in Spring Framework Reference Manual about JPA. You should also read the part about transaction management in previous chapters.

Comment: Thanks for the update; I had the same idea in mind, but I assumed that spring might have is own implementation of the lower level operations. In this case, I will stick with using my current implementation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if we can do what you request.
But I have an alternative to your method.

```
public List<Person> getPersons(List<Long> perIds) {
    return em.createQuery(
        "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.perId = " 
        + org.springframework.util.StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(perIds, " OR p.perId = ", "'", "'")
    ).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: That is a pretty convenient method! I will keep that in mind for the future, but it isn't quite what I am looking for. From what I understand, my intent may not be possible in Spring. Thanks for the tip though! I will look through that library and wee what else it has.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the `IN` query condition instead?

Spring should allow you to do:

```
@Query( "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.perId in :ids" )
findPersonsInIdList(@Param("ids") List<Long> perIds);
```

Comment: Your solution would work for that specific query, however, I have other queries generated from more complex algorithms which simply would not be able to be solved using a method such as this. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score -1):

Please consider the below example.May be you are looking something like this.Though your question is not pretty straight forward what do you want.Using criteria or specification you can achieve many cool things.

```
@Service 

Optional<Person> findByEmail(String email);


@NoRepositoryBean
public interface PersonRepositoryCustom {
    Optional<Person> findByEmail(String email);
}

@Repository
public class PersonRepositoryImpl extends QuerydslRepositorySupport implements PersonRepositoryCustom {
    public PersonRepositoryImpl() {
        super(Person.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Person> findByEmail(String email) {
        JPAQuery<Person> query = getQuerydsl()
                .createQuery()
                .from(QPerson.person)
                .where(QPerson.person.email.equalsIgnoreCase(email))
                .select(QPerson.person);
        return query.fetch().stream().findFirst();
    }
}
```